# JS objects: how to Dynamically name members when adding properties

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, member

I'm trying to create new object member with a dynamically created string as the member name:

```
  > obA = {};
  > obb = {name:'jim', age:22};
  > var s = new String(obb.name);
  > obb;                       //{ name: 'jim', age: 22 }
  > obA.s = obb;               //{ name: 'jim', age: 22 }
  > obc = {name:'don', age:23};
  > var c = new String(obc.name);
  > obA.c = obc;
  > obA;
        outputs the folowing
             { s: { name: 'jim', age: 22 },
               c: { name: 'don', age: 23 } }
```

In this example I would like to add members  **'jim'** and **'don'** to **obA**, not **'s'**  and **'c'**.  Instead my calls above add members **'s'** and **'c'**.  Is there some way to dynamically name the members so that I can add **'jim'** and **'don'** at runtime without knowing the member names ahead of time.  What I want from  in the above example from **'obA'** at the end is:

```
  > obA;
   // should output
        { jim: { name: 'jim', age: 22 },
          don: { name: 'don', age: 23 } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obA[obb.name] = obb;
obA[obc.name] = obc;
```

Comment: Thanks,  exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Use bracket notation.

```
obj['property'] = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `[]` instead of dot.

```
obA[s] = obb;
obA[c] = obc;
```